# canActivate returning Promise or Observable blocks Change detection

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, canactivate

When I add canActivate that returns either an Observable or Promise (in this case a promise) the routing works correctly but it seems to block things like (click) events, pipes don't work correctly, etc... These functions all work as soon as I make canActivate just return true. Any suggestions?

canActivate

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):  Observable<boolean> | boolean | Promise<boolean> {
return Stamplay.User.currentUser()
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.user) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }).catch(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    });
```

[image: For example, the material search doesn't work with canActivate/]

For example, the material search doesn't work with canActivate, but works perfectly when I just return true or take canActivate out.

Comment: Then you can try returning a resolved promise ! instead of returning true or false, return `Promise.resolve(true)` and `Promise.reject(false)`

Comment: @trichetriche Thanks, that worked! I think it would be helpful for others, so if you make an answer I can mark it correct.

Comment: No problem, did it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following my comment, return `Promise.resolve(true)` and `Promise.reject(false)` instead of returning true and false.